# Why is my C program stopping just before a printf?

Tags: c, printf

The program that I am trying to make is pretty much one that plots a point as it moves around the center of the screen as if affected by gravity. The method I'm using as a "display" is simply printing a " " where there is no point and an "X" where there is a point. After finishing writing my program and noticing it didn't work exactly how I wanted it to, I proceeded to begin debugging it. The full program is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double dist (double xpos, double ypos, double xm, double ym);
double acc (double xpos, double ypos, double xm, double ym, double grav, int xory);

int main () {
    double xpos, ypos, xvel, yvel, xm, ym, grav, step;
    double xtpos, ytpos, xtvel, ytvel;
    int refresh, width, height;
    int xposr, yposr, xmr, ymr;

    xpos = 3;
    ypos = 4;
    xvel = 0;
    yvel = 0;
    grav = 4;
    step = 1;
    xm = 0;
    ym = 0;
    width = 128;
    height = 64;
    refresh = 1;

    int screen[width][height];
    printf ("done2\n");
    printf ("test\n");
    printf ("done3");
    while (refresh == 1) {
        printf ("entered loop");
        usleep (100000);
        for (int a = 0; a <= height; ++a) {
            for (int b = 0; b <= width; ++b) {
                screen[b][a] = 0;
            }
        }
        xposr = rint (xpos);
        yposr = rint (ypos);
        xmr = rint (xm);
        ymr = rint (ym);
        screen[xmr][ymr] = 1;
        screen[xposr][yposr] = 1;

        for (int y = 0; y <= height; ++y) {
            for (int x = 0; x <= width; ++x) {
                if (screen [x][y] == 0) {
                    printf (" ");
                }
                else {
                    printf ("X");
                }
            }
            printf ("\n");
        }

        xtpos = xpos + (xvel * step);
        ytpos = ypos + (yvel * step);
        xtvel = xvel + (acc (xpos, ypos, xm, ym, grav, 0) * step * step);
        ytvel = yvel + (acc (xpos, ypos, xm, ym, grav, 1) * step * step);

        xpos = xtpos;
        ypos = ytpos;
        xvel = ytvel;
        yvel = xtvel;
        refresh = 0;
    }
}

double dist (double xpos, double ypos, double xm, double ym) {
    double deltax, deltay, result;
    deltax = xpos - xm;
    deltay = ypos - ym;
    result = sqrt ((deltax * deltax) + (deltay * deltay));
    return result;
}

double acc (double xpos, double ypos, double xm, double ym, double grav, int xory) {
    double result;
    if (xory == 0) {
        result = ((xpos - xm) * grav * grav) / (dist (xpos, ypos, xm, ym) * dist (xpos, ypos, xm, ym) * dist (xpos, ypos, xm, ym));
    }
    else if (xory == 1) {
        result = ((ypos - ym) * grav * grav) / (dist (xpos, ypos, xm, ym) * dist (xpos, ypos, xm, ym) * dist (xpos, ypos, xm, ym));
    }
    return result;
}
```

The program seemed to hang up and never enter the while loop which could been seen because no "entered loop" text was printed on the screen. This is quite strange as the while loop should go on infinitely because refresh == 1. I then put some printf statements just before the while to see where the program stopped. At this point, the only thing I get after running the program is

```
done2
test
|
```

For some reason, the program isn't even bothering to do the next printf statement.

Comment: `stdout` is line buffered

Comment: That nothing is printed is not your big problem, it's that you have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your code. You're writing outside the boundaries in your arrays.

Comment: ... And writing outside the array is probably clobbering the width and height variables with 0 during the a-b for loop, so the y-x for loop probably doesn't execute any printfs.

Answer (score 3):

`printf` writes to a special `FILE *` called `stdout`.  `printf(/*...*/)` is synonymous with `fprintf(stdout, /*.../*)`.  For performance reasons mostly, stdout is *line buffered*, meaning that anything written to it may not be outwardly visible until you have written a newline to it or flushed it manually.  Outputting characters is costly, by buffering the output we can output fewer times and our programs run much, much faster.

If you aren't outputting to a file, you can get it to flush on every print by saying

```
printf("entered loop\n"); // note the extra '\n'
```

if you're writing just text (not a format string, not printing any variables) you can also use `puts(const char *)` which prints the string you give it followed by a newline.

```
puts("entered loop");
```

stdout is fully buffered when outputting to a file (not the screen).  The following will always cause it to flush.  If you want your output to stay exactly as you have written it, this is the way to do it:

```
printf("entered loop");
fflush(stdout);
```

---

if you want to live dangerously you could do

```
setbuf(stdout, NULL);
```

once in your main, or elsewhere, which will prevent all buffering on stdout (by dangerously I mean really slowly and you probably shouldn't actually do this).

Answer (score 2):

You should include a line feed character in printf:

```
printf("entered loop\n");
```

This will cause the buffer to flush. Without it, the characters will not get actually printed on the console. BTW, this is also the reason you don't see the "done3" printed, it also lacks the "\n".

Alternatively, you can flush it manually:

```
printf("entered loop");
fflush(stdout);
```

The reason it's necessary is that stdout is a buffered device (well, it holds true on some *nix systems). It means that it will not get printed on the screen unless the buffer is filled, it's flushed manually or you include the new line character in the printed text.

Comment: That, or `fflush(stdout)`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the problems identified by kamituel and Ryan Haining, your program has the following issues:

- the loops iterating over dimensions of the `screen` matrix should stop when the index reaches the size of the given dimension, excluded.  You must use `a < height` instead of `<=`.  This mistake must be corrected in at least 4 separate instances.
- it is more common to define the matrix `screen` as `int screen[height][width];` as it allows better locality in the nested loops with `y` iterating in the outer one and `x` in the inner one.  The code is not incorrect as posted, but somewhat surprising.
- function `acc()` returns uninitialized variable `result` if `xory` is neither `0` nor `1`.  If correctly configured, the compiler should produce a warning for this and other potential problems.  If `xory` is just a boolean, a single test would suffice.
- the loop `while (refresh == 1)` seems to iterate exactly once. Why make it a loop?